# Android: Initialize a two dimensional array of type <class>

Tags: android, arrays, class, multidimensional-array

I'm sure that this is some basic misunderstanding on my part, but ...

I want to have a class:

```
public class Foo {
   String bar;
}
```

And the declare a two dimensional array of them:

```
Foo[][] foobar = new Foo[3][3];
```

Which works fine, but when I get to that point and look at foobar, each element is null.  Now I can initialize each element at this point, but this just seems wrong.  I don't know if I need to have some special constructor in my class or what.

I'm new to Android and Java, so any help would be appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

you do have to initialize each element. what you're doing is creating an empty 2 dimensional array of 9 elements. what you can do, however is to have a for loop nested within another for loop that initializes each element to a new Object() (or whatever class you need). in that case nothing will be null.